# Getting window.location in embedded Flash

Tags: javascript, html, flex4

I embed a .swf file in HTML and then embed this HTML itself in another HTML.

In the .swf file I call

```
ExternalInterface.call(" function(){ return window.location.toString();}";
```

The problem is sometimes I seem to get window location of the embedded HTML and sometimes I get address of the main HTML (see picture).

[image]

All I am after is reliability. I want to get the same address everytime. I haven't even been able to understand when it get which location. I wonder if it is some sort of browser related mystery!

Thanks for any help
Cheers!

Ali

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded HTML"? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `window.top.location.href` should always give you the address the user sees in their location bar.  Be wary of using `.toString()` on DOM objects in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: thank you so much! it worked!     but I didn't really understand the warning about the older IE versions. Could you explain a bit?